# How Can I Solve Product Zooming Images Extracting as Two Imges

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images, zoom

When i try to zooming Products Image, Its Extracting as a two images in box,  How can i solve this Extracting  error.

[image]

Comment: Is any suitable zoom extensible for sample data theme.

Comment: Any other remedies may as you know.

Comment: Cloud zoom extension ?

Comment: @GopalPatel   yes, am using cloud zoom

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9277462/7089203  basically your image is small thats why it is repeating